# Как убрать границу (обводку) у кнопки

Tags: html, css

Примитивный вопрос фронтендерам. Я пишу сайт, используя css фреймворк SPECTRE. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не получается убрать границу у дефолтной кнопки, построенной на этом фреймворке. Причём в обычном состоянии границы нет, но при фокусе она появляется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже всё перепробовал и outline, и border, и background none, и при :focuse но ничего не выходит
[Ссылка на сайт фреймворка](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/elements/buttons.html)

Код:

```css
.menu-btn{
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        background: none;
    }

    .menu-btn:focus{
        border: none; 
        outline: none;
        background: none;
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-lg menu-btn btn-link text-primary"><i class="icon icon-menu"></i></button>
```

Comment: `box-shadow: none`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, но я что-то не понял как они тень к границе приспособили

Comment: В смысле? Просто классу `.btn` прописали св-во `box-shadow`. Посмотрите в DevTools